# VBA Excel macro can't create SortedList

Tags: excel, vba, com-interop

I have a VBA macro that runs in Excel and uses a SortedList. On most machines it runs fine. On one, the line

```
Dim myEvents As New SortedList
```

results in myEvents having a value of Nothing. The line

```
myEvents = createobject("system.collections.sortedlist")
```

causes an "Automation Error". mscorlib.dll is in my References and is checked.

Anybody have any idea what's going on? Since the macro works on other machines I think it must be some system setup problem, but I don't know what it could be.

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362
System Model    Surface Laptop
System Type x64-based PC
```

Comment: put `Set` before `myEvents =` - it's an object.

Comment: The bitness of the OS is irrelevant. The bitness of the Office install however, makes all the difference. Is everyone on 64-bit Office?

Comment: Still no solution. Office is 32 bit on all machines. mscorlib is not ticked in References. CreateObject still returns the "Automation Error".

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Dim myEvents As New SortedList
> ```

For an early-bound, [auto-instantiated](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SelfAssignedDeclaration) declaration to result in `myEvents` being `Nothing`, things need to be very, very, very broken.

Because the minute an auto-instantiated object is created, you can never test it for `Nothing` and get `True` - this assertion can never be met, because the mere referencing of `myEvents` in the expression is enough for VBA to go and re-instantiate the object before it evaluates `Is Nothing`:

```
Debug.Assert myEvents Is Nothing
```

You can only declare something `As SortedList` with a project reference to the type library that defines this class.

> ```
> myEvents = createobject("system.collections.sortedlist")
> ```

Two problems here: one, the `Set` keyword is missing. We're assigning an object reference, `Set` is required. Next is the use of `CreateObject` to make a `New` instance of a type that's defined in a library that's already loaded and referenced: the compiler already knows where to find the type, but you're making it hit the Windows Registry to find out regardless. `New` it up instead, and keep `CreateObject` for things defined in libraries that are NOT referenced.

```
Set myEvents = New SortedList
```

That should be all you need, assuming the reference is correct.

> mscorlib.dll is in my References and is checked.

Not the DLL, but the TLB. And it has to be of the correct bitness for the computer that's going to run it, and the correct bitness is going to have to match the bitness of the host application, i.e. Excel.

You can't early-bind to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\` and have it work in 32-bit Excel. And you can't early-bind to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` and have it work in 64-bit Excel.

If some of your users are using a different bitness install of Office, either fix their install to match everyone else's, or remove the reference and use late binding:

```
Dim myEvents As Object
Set myEvents = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
```

On the down side you'll be coding in the dark, without compiler assistance and with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.8) nearby.

On the up side, the late-bound code should work on all Windows systems.

Comment: Setting a VBA project reference to "mscorlib.tlb" is shown in the "Available References" listbox as a checked "mscorlb.dll" which corresponds to the "Location:" as  "C:\...\mscorlib.tlb". So I think the reference is indeed set correctly.

Comment: @Gene this early binding is also the reason for OP's trouble, if you read the rest of the answer.

Comment: I am not disputing your answer. I am just pointing out that setting the reference to .tlb is DISPLAIED by VBA project as a reference to .dll. Actually, it is IMPOSSIBLE to set reference to .dll in this case :)

Comment: And you've late-bound everything (`As Object`) and removed the project reference to mscorlib.tlb/dll?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I'm still stuck, though. Using CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") throws an "Automation Error", still. References contains mscorlib.dll, not mscorlib.tlb. Is the missing .tlb the problem perhaps? I have the latest Office, but I don't know where to look to determine if it's 32 or 64 bit. Where's that information?

Comment: Technicality, but you can't reference a .net dll in VBA - the reference is loading the .tlb, which is loading the .dll. And you DO NOT want either referenced, and you do not want ANY declaration (`As .....`) to be referring to any type defined in that library. Use `As Object` to late bind everything.

Comment: You can find out if Excel is 32 or 64 bit from File/Account/About Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Did a quick search for mscorlib.tlb. Found it under Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework and also under Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 - which means I think I have .Net for both 32- and 64-bit systems?

Comment: Yes, and the VBE will only let you reference one of the two, and if your users are on a different bitness of Excel than you, then the hard-wired reference will make them fail to compile. Hence, REMOVE the reference and late-bind everything.

Comment: Again thanks, but you see above that I have removed the hard-wired reference and switched to the late-bind method and it gives me an "Automation Error", no further explanation.

Comment: Close everything and then try `Set foo = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")` in a brand new VBA project. If that doesn't blow up, then maybe your VBA project is corrupted. If it does blow up.... I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: Nope. Still throws "Automation Error" even with a brand new project. Also, all my Offices are 32-bit, on machines where it works and machines where it doesn't.

Comment: I wish I could help more. Try repairing your .NET framework - works perfectly fine here.

Comment: This is with mscorlib not checked. Only checked items in References are "Visual Basic for Applications", "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library", "OLE Automation", "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library".

Comment: That's exactly as it should be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out the problem was the reference before mscorlib wasn't found, in this case the **Tools > Reference** page had "MISSING: Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library". I solved it by unticking the missing library, selecting ok then re-adding the mscorlib reference.